# Find the differences in contents of documents between versions - Document Library

Tags: development, sharepoint-server

I want to compare the version updates and  the content of a document which stored in document library using document version.

For example: one word document has 3 versions,

Version 1.0 contents : Please

Version 2.0 contents : Please Help

Version 3.0 contents : Please Help Me

Now, either the difference of these version should be highlighted like Version 2.0 in Help, Version 3.0 as Help Me or show only the differences.

Need to generate a report of comparison between each version of the document and display the differences.